# Где применяются не бинарные деревья?

Tags: c#, c++, алгоритм, дерево

Здравствуйте. Я пишу не большую консольную программку на тему не бинарных деревьев, и не знаю какую именно программу писать.

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, какую не большую консольную программу можно написать с применением не бинарных деревьев?**

(Просто реально не знаю где применить эти деревья, так что бы при этом программа не была слишком сложной в реализации.(т.е. например писать XML парсер для меня пока сложновато, нужно что нибудь по проще))

Comment: Тогда напишите что-нибудь абстрактное.

Например, есть 

     struct treedata {
        char *node_name, *data;
     };

Вводите такие структуры (с клавиатуры или из файла(ов) (вкл. свою фантазию)) и каждой задаете имя узла родителя.

     struct node *insert_node (char *parent_name, struct treedata *node);

Структуру `struct node` (из них состоит все дерево) и набор функций для работы с деревом придумайте сами (а то совсем неинтересно будет).

Потом можете подумать (при желлании), как приделать к такому дереву хэш-таблицу (мультихэш?) для быстрого поиска по именам.

Comment: раз xml - это сложно (но более-менее функциональный парсер - это около 500 строк с++ кода), напишите [YAML](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) парсер. Можно даже взять какое-нибудь мелкое подмножество.

Если это сложно, то можно взять административное деление. То есть, есть столица, ей подчиняются области (округа/республики/регионы/штаты), в их состав входят районы (графства/уезды), а в них в свою очередь города, села, деревни, и так далее.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо. Сам класс для произвольного дерева я реализовал. 
@KoVadim А какие алгоритмы могут использоваться для работы с произвольным деревом?(просто в проге хорошо бы использовать какой нибудь алгоритм)
@avp A при реализации поиска по именам именно произвольные деревья используются, а не бинарные? Просто не пойму, как произвольное дерево использовать для поиска(не превратив его при этом в бинарное)

Comment: @vvtvvtvvt, в бинарном дереве у каждого узла *максимум* 2 потомка, а в произвольном *неограничено*. 

Поиск же осуществляется (например) рекурсивным перебором списка всех деревьев-потомков.

Вам структуру узла произвольного дерева нарисовать, или сами хотите подумать?

Comment: есть ещё один вариант - парсер арифметических выражений в дерево. модно и стильно:)

на входе 2*2+2

на выходе

    +
      2
      *
       2
       2

Хотя оно и достаточно бинарно... Но кто мешает ввести тернарный оператор. Также можно парсить функции с множеством аргументов - будет все полноценно.

Answer (score 2):

> Просто реально не знаю где применить эти деревья

Можно написать приложение, которое строит генеалогическое древо, и введя в консоли имя человека, можно получить имена всех его ближайших родственников.